# add items to dropdownlist in flutter com Parse app4back

Tags: flutter, parsing, dropdown

In flutter, using app4back's Parse, how can I convert response.results to DropdownButtonFormField?
I want to populate a DropdownButtonFormField using parse result

```
Future<List<ParseObject>> getVeiculos() async {
    QueryBuilder<ParseObject> parseQuery =
        QueryBuilder<ParseObject>(ParseObject('Veiculos'));

    parseQuery.whereContains('usuario', currentUser.objectId);

    final ParseResponse apiResponse = await parseQuery.query();

    if (apiResponse.success && apiResponse.results != null) {   
      return apiResponse.results;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
```

Comment: List of what, list of object or list of sting?

Comment: I rephrased the question